# Density impulse of monopropellant hydrazine?

Tags: fuel, liquid-fuel, monopropellant

I only found sources ([like this](http://www.braeunig.us/space/propel.htm) ) giving impulse density of hydrazine used as a bipropellant in conjunction with various oxidizers, but I was unable to find any that would give me density impulse of monopropellant hydrazine... does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the density of hydrazine is $1.021 \frac{kg}{L}$, and its $I_{sp}$ is $220 s$ as a mono propellant. (Both values from the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrazine)).

That is a total of $224.6 \frac{kg \cdot s}{L}$, using the same units as your source.